# Partial fraction decomposition involving imaginary numbers and two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-fractions

I am trying to find a partial fraction decomposition for the following:

$$\frac{1}{(-\alpha xi+4y)(\alpha xi + 2y)}$$

where $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$. I am understanding that I could write this expression as a partial fraction decomposition as:

$$\frac{1}{(-\alpha xi+4y)(\alpha xi + 2y)}=\frac{A}{-\alpha xi+4y}+\frac{B}{\alpha xi+2y}~~(*)$$

but considering that this yields

$$1=A(\alpha xi+2y)+B(-\alpha xi+4y)\implies \\
1=A\alpha xi+2Ay-B\alpha xi+4By \implies \\1=(A - B)\alpha xi+(2A+4B)y$$

I cannot understand what has gone wrong here, since this does not seem to yield any reasonable answers, at least as far as I understand. Has something gone wrong in my decomposition in $(*)$?

Comment: Why do you think the answer you have is unreasonable?  The denominator of your fraction is complex.  Why shouldn't $A,B$ be complex?  If you know $x,y$ are real you can equate the real and imaginary parts to find $A,B$ because that gives two equations.

Comment: See my answer, which agrees with your work.  The key is that since the numerator is $1$, you must have $A - B = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following analysis assumes that $0 \neq x,y,a$.

As Ross Millikan's comment indicates, I am also assuming that $x,y \in \Bbb{R}.$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{(-axi + 4y)(axi + 2y)} = 
\frac{A}{-axi + 4y} + \frac{B}{axi + 2y} \implies$

$$A(axi + 2y) + B(-axi + 4y) = 1.$$

This implies that $A - B = 0$ and $(2y)(A + 2B) = 1.$

So, you have two linear equations in the $2$ unknowns, $A$ and $B$.

Comment: You are assuming that $x,y$ are real, which seems reasonable but OP did not specify.  I would state the assumption at the outset.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks, good catch, answer edited.